# How can I start apache derby programmatically jar file?

Tags: java, jar, derby

I have a Java application, which uses Apache Derby. Using Eclipse Export option, I exported it as JAR file. When I am running Eclipse, and the server is connected to port 1527, the JAR executes correctly.

However when eclipse is closed, (and the server is not connected to 1527) on executing jar, i get this error

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException
>   : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message
>   Connection refused.

This is understandable. But i want to distribute the JAR. So is there a way to start the server programmatically, whenever JAR is executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start the [NetworkServer](http://db.apache.org/derby/javadoc/publishedapi/jdbc4/org/apache/derby/drda/NetworkServerControl.html) programmatically:

```
NetworkServerControl serverControl = new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("myhost"),1621)

serverControl.shutdown();
```

Comment: where can I specify the name of the database ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy You don't need to. The server will just wait for connection requests that will specify the database name like this:  jdbc:derby://myhost:1621/database_name_here

Answer (score 4):

Simplest is to use embedded Derby

```
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + DATA_STORE + ";create=true");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the server programmatically.

How this is done is documented in the manual:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/tadminconfig814963.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.