# Netbeans project using Embedded Server

Tags: netbeans, jdbc, derby

So far I have succeeded in creating java desktop application with embedded driver, but it can accept only one connection at a time. I need to make it work in Server mode, making it possible to have multiple conncetions. I think I need to use NetworkServerControl, but I have no idea how to use it, please help me. A simple sample application will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How to start NetworkServerControl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725376/how-can-i-start-apache-derby-programmaticaly-jar-file

Answer (score 1):

The architecture you want is called "Derby Embedded Server", which you can plug into your search engine, or start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html#Embedded+Server and here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/cadminov825149.html

Comment: Thanks @peter. I tried that and worked fine on my cmputer. I used NetworkServerControl server = new NetworkServerControl();
server.start (null);. However, when I tried my program on another computer it showed exception: SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net. ... connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect. But when I was testing it on my computer it worked fine, both from Netbeans and jar file worked. What can be the problem. The only difference is the other computer had jre 6, but I used jre 7. can that be the cause?

Comment: I'm not sure what "I tried my program on another computer" means, precisely, but note that "localhost:1527" is only available on 1 computer at a time -- all the clients must be on the same "localhost" as the server. If you want access from another machine, you have to use a valid externally-available network address, such as a routable IP address or your machine's network name (myhost.example.com)

Comment: OK. I found my problem. I had two conditions when connection should be established. I forgot about the second one, so after taking that condition into account I was able to run my jar file on any computer successfully. And I want to ask one more question, should I stop my server when my program is exited? or is it stopped automatically? or is it not necessary?

Comment: The server will stop automatically; it is just Java code running on another thread in your JVM. Shutting down your databases prior to exiting your program will help ensure that Derby doesn't have any transaction log recovery work to do when it starts up the next time.