# Java DB doesn't run without NetBean

Tags: java, netbeans-7, javadb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I start apache derby programmatically jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725376/how-can-i-start-apache-derby-programmatically-jar-file)

I have created a desktop application that holds some customer's information. The program

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
 try{ 
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");  
Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/data;create=true;user=APP;password=app");  

String id = jTextField1.getText();  
String name = jTextField2.getText();  


String query = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(id, Name) VALUES (' "+id+" ',' "+name+"')";  
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
int executeUpdate = stmt.executeUpdate(query);  
int ans =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Record Saved Successfully. Do you want to Add More Data ?");  
if (ans== JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){  
       this.dispose();  
   window1 newWindow = new window1();  
newWindow.setVisible(true);  
}  


}  
catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {  
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot Save!!");  

}           
}
```

Alternately If I start `startNetworkServer.bat` in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\db\bin
this works fine.

But How do start that bat file automatically ?