# Starting apache derby programmatically

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

I am a newbie to java. In, my project, I have used JDBC. It worked fine till netbeans was on. But, when I turned off netbeans and executed the jar file, I got the following error :-

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error 
connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
```

I read this answer at -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725496/2464420,but I could not achieve the desired result. I got the following:-


[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a compilation error in your project
You must add derbynet.jar dependency in your classpath in order to embed the server.

http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html#ns_config_env

Client and server dependencies are two different jar.