# Starting network server using Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I got the following code(Command Line) from http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/tadminconfig814963.html :-

```
java -Dderby.drda.startNetworkServer=true
-Dderby.drda.portNumber=1110
-Dderby.drda.host=myhost yourApp
```

Now, I am very confused regarding these two fields:-
**myHost** - Is it *"localhost"*?

and

**yourApp**- Is it the full location of my app?

I am using netbeans and I am a novice in java. So, please provide details...

Comment: Since you are using NetBeans IDE, you could probably try https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

Comment: @Sandhu The problem is that, I can start the server using netbeans but not when the jar is created..

Comment: Create the JAR with Netbeans

Comment: @m0skit0 , I created the jar, but it gives `SQLNonTransientConnectionException` when run in a different computer. So, I have to start the server manually

Comment: @m0skit0 , am I going right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting apache derby programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031034/starting-apache-derby-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

yourapp is tha main class for your java application.
myHost is the address that derby will listen on - localhost will cause it to not receive connections from other computers

Comment: is yourapp the full location of the class? or is it just the class name

Comment: it should be the fully qualified name of the class (including package). if you need more help with invoking java applications from the command line you should really read up on the java classpath - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath is a good starting point

Comment: And what is myHost, can u please give an example? I am really confused.

Comment: a process (no matter what language its written in) listens on a specific port on a specific interface. when you tell a process to listen on "localhost" it will only accept connections coming in from other processes on the same machine. a computer might have several network interfaces and so several IPs/addresses. you need to set which one you want to listen on. most places "0.0.0.0" means "all"