# Small java application with local database? Which database to use?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to create a small java application which allows to connect to a database and exchange information.
It should be possible to start the DB via Java, so I don't need anything but my application to work with the DB. (Not like XAMPP where I need the XAMPP menu to start the DB server for example)

What DB should I use for such a project?

Answer (score 2):

The JDK comes bundled with [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) which is a fully functional RDBMS that is suited for small scale apps and small scale databases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725376/how-can-i-start-apache-derby-programmatically-jar-file

Comment: Java DB unfortunately looks not quite comfortable for me. I created a database via ij. But the administration in java code, like create table, cofuses me. I'm looking for a good tutorial but didn't find one yet :/

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/getstart/index.html  take a look at "Activity 3: Run a JDBC program using the embedded driver" and "The WwdEmbedded program"

Comment: Java DB SQL reference http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try H2 DB, its pretty light weight and suited for small applications. If you want to move the same application at a later stage to any RDBMS, you can take mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to experiment with your small application use Java DB (Previously known as Derby). If you are using JDK 7 then it comes bundled with the JDK. For older versions of JDK you have to download the Derby database from 
https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html